# Finding a formula that is the logical consequence of $(C \implies B) \iff \lnot A$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is it true that $F := (C \implies B) \iff \lnot A \equiv \bot$? Therefore shouldn't any formula be the logical consequence of $F$?

My reasoning is that: $(C \implies B) \iff \lnot A \equiv ((C \implies B) \implies \lnot A) \land  (\lnot A \implies (C \implies B)) \equiv (\lnot(\lnot C \lor B) \lor \lnot A) \land  (\lnot\lnot A \lor (\lnot C \lor B)) \equiv \lnot((\lnot C \lor B) \land A) \land  (A \lor (\lnot C \lor B))$.

Thus the LHS of the middle AND is true only if both $A$ and $\lnot C \lor B$ are false, i.e exactly when $A = False, C = True, B = False$. Thus with this valuation if RHS is false. Therefore the formula couldn't be true in any valuation.

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* logical conseqwuence of a statement. Any statement has an infinite number of logical consequences. If your task is to find *some* logical consequence of $(C \implies B) \iff \lnot A$, then you can just pick $(C \implies B) \iff \lnot A$ itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS of the middle AND is true whenever *either* $A$ or $\neg C\vee B$ is false; you don't need both of them to be false (since you are negating an AND, not an OR).

You can quickly see more directly that the original formula is not a contradiction.  It says that $C\to B$ and $\neg A$ have the same truth value.  Therefore, you can assign $C$ and $B$ any truth values you want, and then assign $A$ the negation of the truth value of $C\to B$, and the formula will be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked, using truth tables (see below), that :

$$\underbrace{((C \implies B) \iff \lnot A)}_F \implies \underbrace{(A \implies (B \land \lnot C))}_G$$

Therefore, as asked, $G$ is a logical consequence of $F$.

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c}
A&B&C&F&G&F \implies G\\
\hline 
0&0&0&1&1&1\\       
0&0&1&0&1&1\\       
0&1&0&1&1&1\\       
0&1&1&1&1&1\\       
1&0&0&0&0&1\\       
1&0&1&1&1&1\\       
1&1&0&0&0&1\\       
1&1&1&0&0&1
\end{array} $$

Comment: Once more, a courageous anonymous downvoting... discouraging good will.

Comment: I understood fully your comment and upvoted your answer...